# How to use Notepad++ to replace "(" with a line break?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I am not sure if this is possible with Notepad++ but I am trying to replace "(" without the quotation with a line break. Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+H to get the Replace dialog

Next to Find what: type `(`

Next to Replace with: type `\n`

Under Search Mode, choose Extended.

Click Replace All

Comment: Wow I had no idea it was that simple... Thanks a lot

Comment: Not problem, but you should thank @lalthomas as it was his suggested edit that originally popped into my queue.